# Problems with App Roles with Facebook Groups - users can't access the app

Tags: facebook, roles, facebook-group

I'm experiencing issues trying to use Facebook's recent feature whereby you can add a Group to an App Role ([announcement blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/531/)).

My app has sandbox mode enabled and I have a Closed group added to the Testers role. After adding a user to the group, I'd expect them to therefore have access to the app, however this isn't the case - they instead see the facebook.com/4oh4.php page.

I appear to have followed the instructions from the blog post correctly. Is anyone experiencing similar issues with trying to use groups with app roles?

Comment: I should add, I originally thought this may be caused by users not being verified, however [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/) say that isn't required for the Testers role and it's also happening to verified accounts.

Comment: There's an open bug report about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/259854244066824

Comment: this feature has been working for me and still is working for me.

Comment: Another update: I've just tried with a different FB app and Group and am seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: @Igy thanks for the link, I've added repro information for FB.

Comment: The same problem here...